In horizontal mode, none of the items in SingleChildScrollView are scrolled in flutter
I have created some items in SingleChildScrollView and the problem is that none of the items are scrolled in horizontal mode, but the same code scrolls the items in vertical mode.
Items are scrollable when scrollDirection: Axis.vertical
It can be scrolled horizontally on the Android platform, but it cannot be scrolled on the web and Windows form.
Scaffold(
  body: RawScrollbar(
    thumbVisibility: true,
    child: SingleChildScrollView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      child: Row(
        children: List.generate(
            50,
            (index) => Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Container(
                      height: 50,
                      color: Colors.blue,
                      child: Center(child: Text('Item $index'))),
                )),
      ),
    ),
  ));

